# Mapped type is missing ValueHolder

Tags: c#, argumentexception

I have a class as follows:

```
  [ValueHolder]
        public class ScenarioData
        {           
            // Dynamic Dictionary Values
            public System.DateTime CurrentDate { get; set; }       
            public Dictionary<string, string> ScenarioProperties { get; set; }
        }
```

I am setting the CurrentDate as follows:

```
return new ScenarioData
            {               
                CurrentDate = DateTime.ParseExact(DateTime.Now.ToString(), "ddMMyyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
}
```

But I get an error: System.ArgumentException = {"Mapped type 'System.DateTime' is missing ValueHolder Attribute."}

Please help me on how to set the CurrentDate.